# Disabling/ changing color for HoverOver in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

I am currently using wpf with a gridview inside a listview. I am able to change the `GridViewColumnHeader` using the code below. However i tried to change the colour/disable for the hover over option using the same `<ListView.Resources>` tag but it does not work. It is currently giving me the default mouse over color light blue which i do not want.

```
<ListView Margin="10,53,10,65" Name="listView" Background=" black" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gridView" >
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn  Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}" >
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Time" Click="lvUsersColumnHeader_Click">Accessed Time</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Username" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}" ></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Location" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}" ></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="File Accessed" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" ></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Remarks" Width="155" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Remarks}" ></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override the default behavior of any control (for example `ListView`), you must define `ControlTemplate` and there are triggers to set the properties. For example like this:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                <Grid>
                ....
```

Without it, the system will take the triggers (and the rest of the behavior) of the default theme, which have their own styles and templates.

To verify this, you can download an example of the style / template for any control on `MSDN`. Example of style for `ListView` is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms788747.aspx).

*`Note:`* Just put the content in `Resources`. It is better to put styles into the file `App.xaml` or in `ResourceDictionary`.

Your example with the style of `MSDN` (a bit large, so you have to decide yourself what to delete and what to leave in style):

```
    <ListView Margin="10,53,10,65" Name="gridview1" Background="Black" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
            <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
            <Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

            <Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
            <Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
            <Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

            <Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
            <Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

            <Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
            <Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
            <Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

            <Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
            <Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


            <Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
            <Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

            <!--Border colors-->
            <Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
            <Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
            <Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

            <Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
            <Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

            <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
            <Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

            <Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

            <!--Control-specific resources.-->
            <Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
            <Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
            <Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

            <Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#000000FF" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#600000FF" Offset="0.4" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#600000FF" Offset="0.6" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#000000FF" Offset="1" />
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

            <Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderGripper" TargetType="Thumb">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="18" />
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                </GradientStopCollection>
                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="Transparent">
                                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                            <Grid>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderBorder">
                                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>

                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                                <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" Padding="2,0,2,0">
                                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                                </GradientStopCollection>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.BorderBrush>

                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                                </GradientStopCollection>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>

                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContent" Margin="0,0,0,1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Border>

                                <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,-9,0" Style="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderGripper}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="Floating">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />

                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                                    <Canvas Name="PART_FloatingHeaderCanvas">
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#60000000" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" />
                                    </Canvas>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="Padding">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                                    <Border Name="HeaderBorder" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}" />
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                    <GradientStopCollection>
                                                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                                                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1.0" />
                                                    </GradientStopCollection>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gridView">
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}" >
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Time">Accessed Time</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Username" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}" ></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Location" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}" ></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="File Accessed" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" ></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Remarks" Width="155" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Remarks}" ></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. However i only need the effect  when i hover over the list view to either disable it or to change into a specific color (Black preferably). Could u help to shorten the code here to suit the requirements? I would really appreciate it thanks

Comment: @user2541163: Without the template you do not change this behavior, I wrote above that. With the help of a template must rewrite the default behavior of the control. This feature WPF.